Azure App Config import cli command: How can I show preview when passing in -y flag
Currently when I try to update azure app config I can do this:
az appconfig kv import -n my-app-config-store --label test -s file --format json --path "file.json" --content-type "application/json" --separator : --depth 3

This will prompt me something like this:
---------------- Key Values Preview ----------------

Updating:
- {"key": "URL", "value": "\"www.test.myapp.com\""}
+ {"key": "URL", "value": "\"www.test2.myapp.com\""}

Do you want to continue?
 (y/n): y

now when I update the command to have -y for my pipeline since I want it to be automated, I stop seeing the preview:
az appconfig kv import -n my-app-config-store --label test -s file --format json --path "file.json" --content-type "application/json" --separator : --depth 3 -y

Is there a way to still show the preview with the -y flag?  I feel like this is very valuable information that we need in our logging.
UPDATE:
I tried:
az appconfig kv import -n my-app-config-store --label test -s file --format json --path "file.json" --content-type "application/json" --separator : --depth 3 && yes | head -n 1

and I got the following:
Unable to prompt for confirmation as no tty available. Use --yes.


What do you mean?


Is there a way to still show the preview with the -y flag? I feel like this is very valuable information that we need in our logging.

No, it is not possible to show the preview when using the -y flag with the az appconfig kv import command. The purpose of the -y flag is to bypass the confirmation prompt and automate the import process.
If you need to check the URL before updating it, you can use the az appconfig kv list command. It will list the URL.
Command and output:
venkatesan@Azure:~$ az appconfig kv list -n sampleconfig --label test --query "[?key=='value'].value" -o tsv
"\"www.test1.myapp.com\""


Now, after verifying the URL, you can use the az appconfig kv import command to update the URL.
Command and output:
 az appconfig kv import -n sampleconfig --label test -s file --format json --path "file.json" --content-type "application/json" --separator : --depth 3 -y
 

Portal:

Reference:
az appconfig kv | Microsoft Learn

I feel like there needs to be a way to see the diff of changes being made.  It seems odd Microsoft would not offer this feature...

I have figured a way to resolve this, at least for myself.
The pipeline step results in an error if the LAST command to be executed has no "--yes".
You can resolve this by adding the actual commit ("--yes") as a second command.
  - task: AzureCLI@2
displayName: 'Import Configurations'
inputs:
  azureSubscription: '...'
  scriptType: 'bash'
  scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
  inlineScript: |
    az appconfig kv import -s file --path my_file.json --format json -n ...
    az appconfig kv import -s file --path my_file.json --format json -n ... **--yes**

This also works if you ONLY want previews, just make the second line import an empty file without a --yes.
This will result in an extra output line:
    ---------------- Key Values Preview ----------------
WARNING: Target configuration already contains all configuration settings in source. No changes will be made.

